# Angular - load select values on page reload

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a combo box 2 that updates when the values of another combo box 1 are selected. To do this I used an `onChange()` function. But when I save my objects and reload the page, only the values of combo box 1 are shown. I think that's because the values of combo box 1 are loaded in the `onInit()` function, while combo box 2 waits for the `onChange()` method to be called.
Is there a way to load the stored values on combo box 2 too? Here's my code (only the relevant part, if other code is needed I'll provide it).

**view**

```
<div>
        <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" [ngModel]="model.mycombo1" name="mycombo1" id="mycombo1">
            <option disabled hidden [value]="unusedValue">Scegli...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let d of combo1" [value]="d.id">{{d.descrizione}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select [ngModel]="model.mycombo2" name="mycombo2" id="mycombo2">
              <option disabled hidden [value]="unusedValue">Scegli...</option>
              <option *ngFor="let d of combo2" [value]="d.id">{{d.descrizione}}</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

**component**

```
export class InsertComponent implements OnInit {

  combo1: Combo[];
  combo2: Combo[];

  constructor(private comboSrv: ComboService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.comboSrv.getCombo1().then(dst => {
      this.combo1 = dst;
    });

  }

  onChange(idCombo1: number) {

    this.comboSrv.getCombo2(idCombo1).then(dst => {
      this.combo2= dst;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: in ngOnInit initialize combo2 using the saved value from combo1 - `this.comboSrv.getCombo2(model.mycombo1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it getting my `combo2` values in the `onInit` function too. Otherwise the view doesn't know how to initialise the combo box when the page loads. Hope this tip helps someone.